# Linq and EntityFramework 4 with multiple inner joins with nested subqueries

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to write Linq query on this Products table based on FacetTypes that need to be grouped by their Facet.

This is the table structure:
[image]

I get passed an array of facetTypeIds, say 9, 6, 52

```
FacetTypeId 9 has a name of "160" and is a Facet of "Size"     
FacetTypeId 6 has a name of "157" and is a Facet of "Size"     
FacetTypeId 52 has a name of "Cool Brand" and is a Facet of "Brand"
```

They need to be constructed into a query that joins based on the facet, like this:

```
select * from products p
inner join (select productId from productFacets where facetTypeId in (9, 6)) 
    p1 on p1.productId = p.productId
inner join (select productId from productFacets where facetTypeId in (52)) 
    p2 on p2.productId = p.productId
```

The outcome is a result set that says:

Get me Products which have brand "Cool Brand" and Sizes of (160 or 157)

How would I go about creating a linq query that will dynamically build this?

I'm kinda stuck as to how this would be formed in linq.

**EDIT:**

This is the code I've sort of come up with however it feels pretty inefficient.

```
MyDbContext _context;

// Groups FacetTypeIds by Facet into int lists 
Dictionary<int, List<int>> createFacetGroup(int[] facetTypeIds)
{
    var facets = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

    var facetTypes = from ft in _context.FacetTypes where facetTypeIds.Contains(ft.FacetTypeId) select ft;
    foreach (var facetType in facetTypes)
    {
        if (facets.ContainsKey(facetType.Facet.FacetId))
            facets[facetType.Facet.FacetId].Add(facetType.FacetTypeId);
        else
            facets.Add(facetType.Facet.FacetId, new List<int> { facetType.FacetTypeId });
    }

    return facets;
}

public List<Product> FindProductsByGroupedFacetTypeIds(int[] facetTypeIds)
{
    var groupedFacetTypeIds = createFacetGroup(facetTypeIds);

    // this seem very inefficient but ToList needs to be called 
    // otherwise the results products in the foreach loop dont end 
    // up with the correct result set
    var products = _context.Products.ToList(); 

    foreach (var facetTypeIdGroup in groupedFacetTypeIds)
    {
        var facetTypeIdGroupArray = facetTypeIdGroup.Value.ToArray();
        products = (from p in products where p.FacetTypes.Any(x => facetTypeIdGroupArray.Contains(x.FacetTypeId)) select p).ToList();
    }

    return products;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the interests of closing this question, i'll submit my solution for this.

It's not pretty but it works. If anyone else has a better solutions, I'd love to see it

```
MyDbContext _context;

// Groups FacetTypeIds by Facet into int lists 
Dictionary<int, List<int>> createFacetGroup(int[] facetTypeIds)
{
    var facets = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

    var facetTypes = from ft in _context.FacetTypes where facetTypeIds.Contains(ft.FacetTypeId) select ft;
    foreach (var facetType in facetTypes)
    {
        if (facets.ContainsKey(facetType.Facet.FacetId))
            facets[facetType.Facet.FacetId].Add(facetType.FacetTypeId);
        else
            facets.Add(facetType.Facet.FacetId, new List<int> { facetType.FacetTypeId });
    }

    return facets;
}

public List<Product> FindProductsByGroupedFacetTypeIds(int[] facetTypeIds)
{
    var groupedFacetTypeIds = createFacetGroup(facetTypeIds);

    // this seem very inefficient but ToList needs to be called 
    // otherwise the results products in the foreach loop dont end 
    // up with the correct result set
    var products = _context.Products.ToList(); 

    foreach (var facetTypeIdGroup in groupedFacetTypeIds)
    {
        var facetTypeIdGroupArray = facetTypeIdGroup.Value.ToArray();
        products = (from p in products where p.FacetTypes.Any(x => facetTypeIdGroupArray.Contains(x.FacetTypeId)) select p).ToList();
    }

    return products;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this
If your entity model name is `YourEntitie` for example :

```
YourEntitie urEntity = new YourEntitie();
List<Products> prdList = (from pro in urEntity.Products.Include("FacetTypes")
                         where (pro.FacetTypes.Where
                                   (fac => fac.FacetTypeID == 9 ||
                                    fac => fac.FacetTypeID == 6).Count() > 0)
                               && (pro.FacetTypes.Where
                                         (fac => fac.FacetTypeID == 52).Count() > 0)
                         select pro).ToList();
```

Comment: cheers, I got your query to work after some tweaks but how would I dynamically build that query based on the given facetTypeIds array?

Comment: I think you want 2 array right ?
one for OR condtions and the other for AND condtions
or maybe one for SIZE and the other for Brands
Is that right ?

Comment: the array can contain many id's. So there will be an uknown amount of facets eg: size, brand, color, shape, weight etc etc